# AWS API Gateway Gzipped JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have got to setup an API endpoint that responds with a catalogue file that is around 18mb JSON file*, which exceeds API Gateways limit of 6mb.

I can gzip compress the file to 256kb however in API Gateway you cannot set Content-Encoding to gzip.

Last November they started allowing binaryMIMETypes however the examples I have seen require the data to be base64 encoded as well ([Standard Lambda Example](https://www.reszelewski.com/2017/03/serving-gzipped-content-from-aws-lambda.html), [Serverless Example](http://forum.serverless.com/t/gzip-response-encoding/1271/7)). Which would then require the client to not just handle GZIP but also Base64.

However the  ([aws-serverless-express example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/blob/master/example/app.js)) seems to include `app.use(compression(())` which makes me think it is possible to send the JSON response gzipped.

I have tried to use the aws-serverless-express example but when I try to npm run setup it fails to create/update the cloud formation stack.

I have a local working Node/Express endpoint working using the following code

```
var express    = require('express'); 
var app        = express();       
var compression = require('compression');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
const cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router(); 

app.use('/api', router);
app.use(compression())
app.use(cors())

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var file = './data/catalogue.json'
    jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
        res.json(obj);   
    })  
});
app.listen(port);
```

I am very new to Lambda and API Gateway so apologies for such a novice question. Can anyone provide any help or advice on how to use Lambda/API Gateway with Gzip JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a very good approach (even without the 6MB limit).

Remember that in using AWS Lambda, you are billed *per 100 milliseconds*. If you are sending this to a lot of users, and each of them will take some time to download it, it will cost you a lot.

My suggestion is for you to store it on S3 (which is very fast), send the S3 link over to the client, and let the client download it from S3.

Comment: took me a while to get the AWS Service Proxy working but yes this is a v clever way to deliver this.